# Alter data type of columns presents in manies tables with sql server script code

Tags: sql-server, alter-table

I'm tring to simplify my task. I'm want to use one script to change data type of all columns name like **xxx_ID** or **Datexxx** present in any table.
Example of column: **Employee_ID, Customer_ID, Periode_ID, Contry_ID, DateInsert, DateUpdate,...**

```
eg: ALTER all TABLE like dbo.tbl_* and all COLUMN like *_ID

///something like this

ALTER TABLE dbo.tbl_*
ALTER COLUMN *_ID varchar(15) NOT NULL

ALTER TABLE dbo.tbl_*
ALTER COLUMN Date* date NOT NULL

////SQL SERVER 2019
```

Can someone have idea?

Comment: You're need to use dynamic SQL to achieve this.

Comment: Basic outline: `SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE('ALTER TABLE $t ALTER COLUMN $c ...','$t', QUOTENAME(t.[name])), '$c', QUOTENAME(c.[name])) FROM sys.tables t JOIN sys.columns c ON ... WHERE t.[name] LIKE ... AND c.[name] LIKE ...` Copy-paste the statements you generate this way to a new window and run. (You can incorporate running the statements in a script as well, but seeing what you're going to do first and having control of the button to push is helpful.)

Comment: Note you also need to consider constraints, indexes, etc. It may be necessary to drop those before altering the column and recreate afterwards.

Comment: Also don't forget to update all of the parameters to functions, stored procedures, anywhere length is assumed in views and other objects, and client/application code that may be applying lengths or constraints on input too.

Comment: hi, thank for all. This haved help me and give me ideas for many things